# How to apply assertions in ROS2 eloquent?

Tags: assert, assertion, ros2

I'm using eloquent and I wanted to add some assertions in my ros2 project.

I tried with the classic `assert()` marco in cpp, but it seems not working very well. I had an `assert(false)` in my code, but when I ran it in debug, the console just said process has died, but not specifying in which function and at which line. I also tried `gdb attach`, again it just said a SIGABRT signal recieved, which is not enough for debugging.

So I turned to ros itself to see if there is any built-in stuff that can be used. I found `ROS_ASSERT()` for ros1, and `rcpputils::assert_true()` for foxy, but nothing for eloquent.

So, how do I effectively assert something in ros2 eloquent? Or did I miss something? Since assertion was already in ros1, I can't find a reason why it's abandoned in ros2.